# Understanding にもかかわらず usage in this context

Tags: grammar

In the recent Kanokari chapter, Ruka was explaining to Kazuya why he shouldn't go out with the rental girlfriend. Below is her dialogue

> 和也はお客で、二人の関係はビジネス
>
> たとえ優しくされたと感じても、それは業務の一環であり、壮大な勘違い
>
> **にもかかわらず**、個人的な交際を申し込むなんて、重大な契約違反
>
> 付き合うどころか、二度と合うことも叶わないでしょう

I'm a bit puzzled by にもかかわらず here. I know what AにもかかわらずB means. It means "despite A, B is still true." I'm not sure how to apply my understanding in this context.

Initially, I thought could understand the third line as

> **Despite all of this**, asking for a private relationship is a serious breach of the contract.

But I am uncertain what is the preceding statement the sentence above is comparing to. Is it "The kindness you receive is part of her job." Can someone enlighten me on this part?

I checked the fan translations for this section and this is how the third line is understood

> If you push for a personal relationship **in spite of that**, you are in a serious breach of the contract.

Is it an accurate way to understand にもかかわらず usage compared to my interpretation?

Comment: You could read it as "Despite what has just been said, ..." but I think "anyway" or "nevertheless" works better. "Anyway, it is a serious breach of contract to ask about private relations."

Comment: Hmm, I think I figured out the part where I got confused. I parsed AにもかかわらずBなんてC as (Aにもかかわらず(BなんてC)) instead of ((AにもかかわらずB)なんてC). Everything makes sense now.